# how to open a file and edit it in wpf

Tags: wpf, openfiledialog

Hi 
I have a textbox and a button named browser. When I click the browser button, my program uses the Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog to display the file name I selected on the textbox. If I want to add one more button named open, when I click open button, the above file could be opened. No matter it's a *.cs file, *.txt or *.xml. Is this possible?
I try to use OpenFileDialog.OpenFile(), doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` it will use whatever is your default program to open the file, like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filePath);
```